# Find the List index of the object containing the closest property value

Tags: c#, linq, list

How can I find the List index of the object containing the closest property value?

Sample, class MyData contains a property Position. class MyDataHandler has a List of MyData and the positions are: 1, 3, 14, 15, 22.

MyDataHandler has a method called GetClosestIndexAt, If the input value is 13, the method must return index 2.

Sample code:

```
public class MyData
{
    public double Position { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyDataHandler
{
    private List<MyData> myDataList = new List<MyData>();

    public MyDataHandler()
    {
        FillMyData(myDataList);
    }

    public int GetClosestIndexAt(double position)
    {
        int index = -1;
        //How to get the index of the closest MyDataList.Position to position value.
        //index = ?????
        return index;
    }

    private void FillMyData(List<MyData> MyDataList)
    {
        //fill the data...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use overloaded [Enumerable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which projects each element of a sequence into a new form by incorporating the element's index:

```
myDataList.Select((d,i) => new { Position = d.Position, Index = i })
          .OrderBy(x => Math.Abs(x.Position - position))
          .Select(x => x.Index)
          .DefaultIfEmpty(-1) // return -1 if there is no data in myDataList
          .First();
```

Better solution with MinBy operator of [MoreLinq](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MoreLinq.Source.MoreEnumerable.MinBy/) (available from NuGet):

```
public int GetClosestIndexAt(double position)
{
    if (!myDataList.Any())
        return -1;

    return myDataList.Select((d,i) => new { Position = d.Position, Index = i })
          .MinBy(x => Math.Abs(x.Position - position))
          .Index;
}
```

---

You can create your own MinBy extension if you don't want to use library:

```
public static TSource MinBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> selector)
{
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> sourceIterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!sourceIterator.MoveNext())            
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Empty sequence");

        var comparer = Comparer<TKey>.Default;
        TSource min = sourceIterator.Current;
        TKey minKey = selector(min);

        while (sourceIterator.MoveNext())
        {
            TSource current = sourceIterator.Current;
            TKey currentKey = selector(current);

            if (comparer.Compare(currentKey, minKey) >= 0)
                continue;

            min = current;
            minKey = currentKey;
        }

        return min;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why using MinBy is a better solution? Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Pedro77 MinBy extension finds the answer in linear time, while an `OrderBy` needs O(N*LogN) time. When the input is very large (many thousands of items) this difference may become a problem, especially if you call `GetClosestIndexAt` multiple times.

Comment: @Pedro77 OrderBy enumerates source and creates ordered copy of it (i.e. it first sorts all items and keeps them, and only then returns min item for you). MinBy on the other hand stores only one single item, which is much better in terms of performance (I find it readable also). And also dasblinkenlight correctly pointed on time usage

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using LINQ, like this:

```
var res = myDataList
    .Select((v, i) => new {Position = v.Position, Index = i}) // Pair up the position and the index
    .OrderBy(p => Math.Abs(p.Position - position))            // Order by the distance
    .First().Index;                                           // Grab the index of the first item
```

The idea is to pair the position with its index in the list, order by the distance from the specific position, grab the first item, and get its index.

You need to deal with the situation when there's no elements in `myDataList` separately. Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/rN3lbH).

Comment: +1 because of use `Min` to avoid possibly expensive sorting with `OrderBy`.

Comment: @KonradKokosa `Min` will give you minimal value of distance, which is `double`. You can't use it here. See my answer. Btw current solution is wrong. Double does not have property `Index`

Comment: @KonradKokosa SergeyBerezovsky's right, using `Min` discards the index. I rolled back to the previous version, and added a demo.

Comment: Your solution is working. Thanks dasblinkenlight, Konrad and Sergey!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, I was rather thinking about selecting with `Where` value is minimal. It will require two list iteration, but still it is better than sorting

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, I've added my alternative solution but yours is of course eligable

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, I believe the most efficient way is to avoid unnecessary sorting of whole data just to get the first element. We can just select it by searching for the element with minimum difference, calculated separately. It requires two list iteration but no sorting. Given:

```
var myDataList = new List<MyData>()
    {
        new MyData() { Name = "Name1", Position = 1.0 },
        new MyData() { Name = "Name3", Position = 3.0 },
        new MyData() { Name = "Name14", Position = 14.0 },
        new MyData() { Name = "Name15", Position = 15.0 },
        new MyData() { Name = "Name22", Position = 22.0 },
    };
double position = 13.0;
```

you can write:

```
var result =
    myDataList.Select((md, index) => new
    {
        Index = index,
        Diff = Math.Abs(md.Position - position)
    })
    .Where(a => a.Diff == myDataList.Min(md => Math.Abs(md.Position - position)))
    .First()
    .Index;
```